# jQuery Tablesorter with jQuery 2.x

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

If I take any simple exmaple for jQuery Tablesorter and run it locally it works fine. If I replace the local link to jquery-latest with a link to a cdn for jquery 2.1.3, it's as if jQuery has not been loaded. All you have to do is replace the src in this "`<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-latest.js"></script>`" with
`"cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"`, and it is like jQuery is not loaded. For example, in the code for the demo for "pager" for Tablesorter: tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Am I missing something dumb, and obvious, and embarrassing, or does Tablesorter not work with the latest jQuery, or... ?

Comment: please provide some sample code; it's easier to troubleshoot that way

Comment: I am new to posting here. When I tried to copy code into the textarea, it edited out anything that looked like html.

Comment: if you want to paste in code, either hit the space bar 4 times, or select the entire code block and then use ctrl-K

Comment: Thank you, nomistic. All you have to do is replace the src in this <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
to this "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" and it is like jQuery is not loaded. For example, in the code for the demo for "pager" for Tablesorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the development console (press F12), you'll see there is a javascript error - try it in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1316/)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

This error is only seen when using jQuery v1.9+. This is because the pager code uses the plugin's internal `clearTableBody` function which checks [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) for IE, and because that function was completely removed in jQuery v1.9+, a javascript error occurs.

So you have three options.

1. Switch to always using jQuery less than v1.9.
2. [Modify the core plugin](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js#L868) and replace this code:

   ```
   this.clearTableBody = function (table) {
       if ($.browser.msie) {
           while (table.tBodies[0].firstChild) {
               table.tBodies[0].removeChild(table.tBodies[0].firstChild);
           }
       } else {
           table.tBodies[0].innerHTML = "";
       }
   };
   ```

   with this

   ```
   this.clearTableBody = function (table) {
       $( table.tBodies[0] ).empty();
   };
   ```
3. Or, try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which does not use `jQuery.browser` and has a bunch of enhancements, useful widgets and parsers. Sadly, most of the widgets are not compatible with the original tablesorter.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for putting so much time into being helpful to a newbie. It's very much appreciated.